# Как вернуть подмножество объектов в типе класса?

Tags: java

Есть класс

```
class ArrayTaskList {
    public Task[] arrayTask = new Task[10];          //массив для хранения тасков
    ..........
    //Остальные методы на подобие как у ArrayList.
    //метод incoming(x,y) возвращает подмножество объектов, которые попадают в 
    //диапазон (task > from && task < to) 
    public ArrayTaskList incoming(int from, int to){ 
    }
}
```

Вопрос: как вернуть подмножество тасков, если нужно, чтобы возвращаемый тип метода `incoming(x,y)` был `ArrayTaskList`? Спасибо.

Comment: Непонятно в чём конкретно проблема. Создать новый `ArrayTaskList` и скопировать туда нужные `Task`'и нельзя?

Comment: @kff вы имеете ввиду новый массив?

Comment: Да. Создаём через `new` новый `ArrayTaskList` и копируем нужное в его поле `arrayTask`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class ArrayTaskList{
    public Task[] arrayTask = new Task[10];          //массив для хранения тасков
    ..........
    //Остальные методы на подобие как у ArrayList.
    //метод inocoming(x,y) возвращает подмножество объектов, которые попадают в 
    //диапазон (task > from && task < to) 
    public ArrayTaskList incoming(int from, int to){ 
    ArrayTaskList toReturn=new ArrayTaskList();
    //ВЫЧИСЛЯЕМ и заполняем массив
    toReturn.arrayTask=new Task[....];
    toReturn.arrayTask[0]=...;
    ...
    return toReturn;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Я бы чуток поправил инициализацию и конструкторы:

```
public class ArrayTaskList {
    public Task[] arrayTask;

    public ArrayTaskList() {
        this.arrayTask = new Task[10];
    }

    public ArrayTaskList(Task[] arrayTask) {
        this.arrayTask = arrayTask;
    }

    public ArrayTaskList incoming(int from, int to) {
        return new ArrayTaskList(Arrays.copyOfRange(this.arrayTask, from, to));
    }

}
```